# How can I groupe dict values into a single array to plot it

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, merge

I am looking for a way to merge the dict values which is composed by 14 arrays into a single array so I can plot it. 
My dict s the following :

```
In [159]:S4_plot
Out[159]: {0: array([ 0.00728011]), 1: array([ 0.01658312]), 2: array([ 0.]),  3: array([ 0.]),  4: array([ 0.]),  5: array([ 0.]), 6: array([ 0.]), 7: array([ 0.]),
 8: array([ 0.007]), 9: array([ 0.01236932]), 10: array([ 0.]),  11: array([ 0.007]), 12: array([ 0.]), 13: array([ 0.]), 14: array([ 0.])}
```

I want to get

```
My_table =[ 0.00728011, 0.01658312, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.007, 0.01236932, 0., 0.007, 0., 0., 0.]
```

When I executed :

```
In[160]:S4_plot.values()
Out[160]: dict_values([array([ 0.00728011]), array([ 0.01658312]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.007]), array([ 0.01236932]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.007]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.]), array([ 0.])])
```

it is a bit complicated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[v.tolist()[0] for k, v in S4_plot.items()]
```

Comment: thank you is working perfectly! I will accept the answer soon

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
## dd = dictionary of array objects

ar = np.concatenate(list(dd.values())).ravel()
```